# Wanted: Text based IDE for Python

Tags: command-line, python, software-recommendation, text-editor, ide

I look for a terminal based IDE for Python on Ubuntu where there are several auxiliary windows for variable inspection and maybe for command history. Something like the Spyder GUI.

Comment: Something like Spyder....   hmmm. install Spyder?

Comment: Try vim, emacs , pico or nano

Comment: Spyder is not terminal based.

Comment: General use editors have no variable inspector function.

Answer (score 0):

I create scientific python applications, so I often have to carry about plenty variables, plots and so on. My favourite is just Ipython3

If you want to see all your variables use:

```
[1] whos
```

To have a look at the whole history (not only current session), you can use the built-in magic command *history*:

```
[2] %history -g
```

If you like spyder and scientific use of pyhton, I recommend you to have a closer look to Ipython3.

You might also have a closer look at gedit.
For gedit you can activate the terminal plugin. So you have one window splitted into text editor and a terminal, where you can run python or Ipython and type your code into .py files simultaneously.